# How to point a pointer column to a specific object in a separate class in Parse?

Tags: javascript, pointers, parse-platform

I created a pointer column (emailAddress) in parse and pointed it to the _User class. But how do I point this to a specific column(email) in the _User class? Is this done in the code or is this done in Parse? I'm building an app in Javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pointers are for references to Classes, you cannot create a Pointer for a Column on a Class.

If you want a copy of a column (e.g. a String `emailAddress` column), you can create an after-save Cloud Function for the `User` class that checks if the `emailAddress` is dirty, and if so updates your other class. I would recommend against this though unless there's a very good reason for doing this.

If you have another class that needs one or more column values from your `User` class the usual way to handle this is to just create a `user` column of type `Pointer<_User>`, then when querying your class just tell it to include the `user` column, e.g.:

```
query.include('user');
```

Then in your `find()` or whatever you use to run the query you can now do the following:

```
var user = results[i].get('user');
var email = user.get('emailAddress');
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Tim! I was expecting that the data will populate in Parse's webapp. But I'm able to query specific items using your above answer. Thanks!